# ionic 3 how to have two Y-scroll in the same page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want the first list not to scroll we you can with the attribute no-bounce. Now the second list is not even showing up. I want that list to appear at the bottom with an Y-scrolll.

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Calendar</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only clear padding>
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content no-bounce>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src="img/avatar-finn.png">
          </ion-avatar>
          <h2>Finn</h2>
          <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
          <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
</ion-content>

<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-avatar item-start>
            <img src="img/avatar-finn.png">
          </ion-avatar>
          <h2>Finn</h2>
          <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
          <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this leveraging ion-scroll:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-scroll scrollX="false" scrollY="false" style="width: 100%; height: 50%">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Finn</h2>
        <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
        <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Finn</h2>
        <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
        <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Finn</h2>
        <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
        <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Finn</h2>
        <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
        <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-scroll>
  <ion-scroll scrollX="false" scrollY="true" style="width: 100%; height: 50%">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Finn</h2>
        <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
        <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Finn</h2>
        <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
        <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Finn</h2>
        <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
        <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Finn</h2>
        <h3>Don't Know What To Do!</h3>
        <p>I've had a pretty messed up day. If we just...</p>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

Each ion-scroll component has controls over the scrolling directions and also you need to set width/height for this element.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you can see **[in the Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/)**:

> ### Scroll
>
> `ion-scroll`
>
> Scroll is a non-flexboxed scroll area that can scroll horizontally or
>   vertically. `ion-scroll` **can be used in places where you may not need a
>   full page scroller, but a highly customized one, such as image scubber
>   or comment scroller**.

Usage

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true">
</ion-scroll>

<ion-scroll scrollY="true">
</ion-scroll>

<ion-scroll scrollX="true" scrollY="true">
</ion-scroll>
```

Input Properties

```
Attr        Type        Details
-------     -------     ----------
maxZoom     number      Set the max zoom amount.    
scrollX     boolean     If true, scrolling along the X axis is enabled.    
scrollY     boolean     If true, scrolling along the Y axis is enabled; requires the following CSS declaration: ion-scroll { white-space: nowrap; }
zoom        boolean     If true, zooming is enabled.
```